# android studio ndk develop, editor can't find ndk headers

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, header

I trying to do some ndk developing using Android Studio 2.0 with Gradle, I downloaded SDK and NDK, and set the paths in settings. But when I trying to play with google's NDK examples, the editor can't find ndk c/c++ header files(like "jni.h" etc.). Although I can compile the project.

I'm on Windows 10 platform, using Android Studio 2.0, I'm using the example from "https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk"

I have done NDK development using Android Studio before on Mac, and things work fine.

Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in AndoridStudio2 Preview version -> [Issue 195483](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483)

are you using this version? If yes then I think you have to wait for an Update

Comment: Well, actually I'm using the stable release version. Looks like they didn't fix this bug in the release version

Comment: This issue is fixed for me using AS 2.1 RC and gradle-experimental 0.7.0-rc1